# LaunchScreen.TemplateiOS target directory

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

in Sydney, when we build an app for iOS there is now a new folder that will be created: `LaunchScreen.TemplateiOS\`. The problem is that it's make a little the mess in the directory structure of my project. Is there any way to specify the directory where the LaunchScreen.TemplateiOS directory must be created ?

NOTE/Update: It's seam their is not any option, you can vote for it here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33503